# Hiding sensitive information python dot-env

Tags: python, github, environment-variables, zsh, dotenv

I'm new to this.
What's the difference between storing sensitive information in a python-dotenv .env file or my zsh.profile? Which is more secure?

Also, I'm starting to learn about GitHub; I know I can add .env to a .gitignore file to hide my information, but can I also use the environment variables stored in zsh.profile when using GitHub? Or Aren't these related?

I hope this makes sense and not is a silly question.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Users with read access to a file can read it. It doesn't matter how you name your file. When you invoke a shell such as `zsh` , there are certain rules on what files are being processed, and where they are located, and you basically control of these issues (see `man zsh`, section _STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES_). Depending on how you do it, files inside your git repo would or would not be processed (see the environment variable `ZDOTDIR` for this).

Answer (score 0):

A typical [python project .gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Python.gitignore) does include `.env` (as being ignored).

That means the `.env` file created by [`python-dotenv`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) is ignored.

But the `.zshrc` is not part of your project Git repository. It is in your `$HOME`. So GitHub would not see it anyway.